# Could not open a connection to your authentication agent. Agent is running, has keys, and is forwarded

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

My configuration for accessing parts of my cloud have seemingly failed, and I can not seem to understand what is going wrong.

My SSH agent is running, my private key has been added, and I've requested that it be forwarded; the authentication is successful when connecting to the first host, but the agent is seemingly never forwarded.

```
$echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
8164

$echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-8u7DguDSY8ws/agent.696

$ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:9ylALlnjZaCA35dZLmvwrMf//O15ZVP71rIf/xfDueg /home/matt/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

Then SSHing to one of my hosts:

```
$ ssh -vvv me@node1.my.network | grep agent
...
debug2: key: /home/matt/.ssh/id_rsa (0x600061780), explicit, agent
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug2: channel 0: request auth-agent-req@openssh.com confirm 0
```

However when I make it to my shell and try and access the agent:

```
me@node1 $ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

> What could be causing this behavior?

I also tried using the 'Allow agent forwarding' option in Putty with the same behavior, I can login to the first host but the agent appears unconnected.